# Trigonometry : Find the length of side

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Can someone tell me how to calculate the length 'd' from the below figure?
[image]

It is from Lecture 06 - Optical flow : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VyLAH8BhF8&index=8&list=PLd3hlSJsX_Imk_BPmB_H3AQjFKZS9XgZm
(At around 16:20 mins.)

Here vector p (to point (u,v)) is resolved into parallel and normal components. So I suppose d is supposed to be perpendicular to the line joining -ft/fy and -ft/fx.

The result for d is also shown in figure. I want to know how to arrive at that.

Comment: Hint: Do you see anything similar in the three triangles in your picture?

Comment: They are right triangles?

Comment: Yes, they are right. Moreover, they are similar to each other (same angles, same ratios of lengths). Perhaps I should have emphasized the word "similar" more in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $w$ is the angle at the lower right, then $\tan w=f_x/f_y$, so you can determine $w$. But then also $\sin w =-df_x/f_t$, so now you can determine $d$.

Comment: how did you get sinw? And how do I arrive at the result shown in the figure above?

Comment: Sine of angle = (opposite side)/(hypotenuse)

Comment: Also, if $\tan \theta =\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}{\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}$, then $\sin\theta = \pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\cos\theta = \pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle whose vertices are the origin, $-f_t/f_x$ and $-f_t/f_y$ are right, and its altitude is $d$.

Then
$$\frac1{d^2}=\frac{f_x^2}{f_t^2}+\frac{f_y^2}{f_t^2}$$

(I have applied [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Right_triangle)).